# Android App History

Tags: android, caching, privacy

Is there any way to tell if an app has been used on an android phone?

I am specifically interested in the camera and gallery functions. I believe my roommate went through my photos without asking, and I've tried to view the cache for the gallery app but can't seem to figure out how to do it. Am I even on the right track? He had it for a twenty minute interval, and I want to see if the gallery was accessed during that period of time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming related problem, unless you wise to program a solution. You may wish to ask your question on [Android Enthusiasts SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Android L(5.0) added [usage statistics API](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html)s. You could write a simple app that checks the timestamps of usage of the gallery application or there might already be one on the app store. It looks like there's a fair number [on the App Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=usage%20statistics&c=apps&hl=en) that provide this functionality but I didn't install any to find out.